# How to check existing file for entries, so not to rewrite data

Tags: database, vbscript

What I've created is a script which pulls the Dell Service code, Username, and Computername, from a computer, and compiles that information into a .csv file. This script will be implemented via Active Directory login scripts, so end users wont have to do a thing.

The problem I'm having though, is everytime a person logs on, it collects their information, and adds it to the list. This means my list could just be full of two people who log onto their computer over and over.

What I would like to happen is for the script to search the .csv file for the specific data collected, and if this data exists, to not enter it.

The code I have so far is this:

```
dim goFS, tsUsers, bFound
set goFS = createObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
set tsUsers = goFS.OpenTextFile("\\xxx\Gathering\DataLog.txt", 2, True)
bFound = False
Do Until tsUsers.AtEndOfStream
   If 1 = Instr(tsUsers.ReadLine(), sUser) Then
     bFound = True
     WScript.Quit (0)
      Exit Do
   End If
Loop
tsUsers.Close
If Not bFound Then
   Set tsUsers = goFS.OpenTextFile("\\xxx\Gathering\DataLog.txt", 8, True)
   tsUsers.WriteLine sUser
   tsUsers.Close
End If

'Get Dell Service Tag Info
set ProSet = GetObject("winmgmts:").InstancesOf("Win32_BIOS")
Set ProSet1 = GetObject("winmgmts:").InstancesOf("Win32_SystemEnclosure")
For each Pro in ProSet
  For each Pro1 in ProSet1
    ServiceTag=Pro.SerialNumber
    exit for
  Next
  exit for
Next

'get username and computername, could also be asked in a batch
Set oShell     = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set oShellEnv  = oShell.Environment("Process")
sComputerName  = oShellEnv("ComputerName")
sUsername      = oShellEnv("username")

dim filesys, filetxt, getname, path
Set filesys = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set filetxt = filesys.OpenTextFile("\\xx\Gathering\DataLog.csv", 8, True, -2)
path = filesys.GetAbsolutePathName("\\xx\Gathering\DataLog.csv")
getname = filesys.GetFileName(path)
filetxt.WriteLine sUsername & ", " & sComputerName & ", " & ServiceTag
filetxt.Close
```

The problem I'm getting is a runtime error: 800A0036 (Bad File Mode) in location (Line 5, Char 1).

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your

```
set tsUsers = goFS.OpenTextFile("\\xxx\Gathering\DataLog.txt", 2, True)
```

opens the file ForWriting.

Cf. [the same last week](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11141008/603855)

Comment: don't I want it to be for writing?

Comment: @KeyferMathewson No; first ForReading to check, then ForAppending to add the new user. I did spell it out here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11141008/603855

Comment: I misread it last one, sorry about that. Now it seems that it isn't writing to the file though, or that the search doesn't even happen. Any ideas?

Comment: @KeyferMathewson If the code you run is *exactly* as you published in your question then you have to pull the 'get username' part to the top and normalize the variable(names) sUser vs. sUserName.